# Get a row in Cassandra by key without using CQL

Tags: cassandra

I have worked with other NoSQL databases that support the concept of a "get" by Primary Key rather than a "select".

The advantage of a "get" is that there is no SQL/CQL/OQL/whatever to parse or process, so it's much much faster.

Is there anything similar in the Cassandra API where I can simply "get" an entire row by primary key without Cassandra having to parse CQL?  (Or is CQL parsing so simple and fast that it makes no measurable difference?)

Comment: "...so it's much much faster." Can you share your supporting metrics?

Comment: Well not for Cassandra, but for other NoSQL databases.  Like GemFire, for example, is a super-fast memory grid, so a "get" takes about 0.1ms, but if you pass an OQL query, it takes 1 or 2 ms.  That's still fast, but an order of magnitude slower than the "get", and for some workloads that can be critical.

Comment: It can be critical. But does the same difference hold true for CQL? Have to measure it to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CQL parsing is fast and low overhead, don't worry about it. If it bothers you you can prepare the statement and have them pre-parsed but network and disk latency will trump it by orders of magnitude.

There is a Thrift interface though if you really want a "get" function. Its deprecated now and in recent versions CQL is faster.